# Cordova diagnostic plugin not working

Tags: android, cordova, phonegap-plugins, phonegap

I am using diagnostic plugin to get information about whether the location is turned on or not. The plugin was working fine until I removed it due to some problem in code.

Now when I have added the plugin again in the same app, it's not working.

Same plugin is working in another app that I created for demo purpose.

I have also tried the legacy version of the diagnostic plugin.

```
function checkLocationEnabled(){
    cordova.plugins.diagnostic.isLocationEnabled(function(enabled){
        alert("Location is " + (enabled ? "enabled" : "disabled"));
        alert(enabled);
        if(enabled == false){
            cordova.plugins.locationAccuracy.canRequest(function(canRequest){
                if(canRequest){
                    cordova.plugins.locationAccuracy.request(function(){
                        alert("GPS turned on");
                        setLatitudeLongitude();
                    }, function (error){
                        alert("Request failed");
                        if(error){
                            // Android only
                            alert("error code="+error.code+"; error message="+error.message);
                            if(error.code !== cordova.plugins.locationAccuracy.ERROR_USER_DISAGREED){
                                if(window.confirm("Failed to automatically set Location Mode to 'High Accuracy'. Would you like to switch to the Location Settings page and do this manually?")){
                                    cordova.plugins.diagnostic.switchToLocationSettings();
                                }
                            }
                        }
                    }, cordova.plugins.locationAccuracy.REQUEST_PRIORITY_HIGH_ACCURACY // iOS will ignore this
                    );
                }
            });
        } else if (enabled == true){
            setLatitudeLongitude();
        }
    }, function(error){
        alert("The following error occurred: "+error);
    });
}
```

entry in my **config.xml** file

```
<plugin name="cordova.plugins.diagnostic" spec="~3.6.5" />
```

**Cordova version: 6.5.0**

Installed platforms:
  **android 6.2.3
  browser 4.1.0
  ios 4.3.1**

```
<preference name="android-minSdkVersion" value="14" />
```

Tried to debug on chrome and the it shows the error 'cannot read property diagnostic' of undefined.

Also I am using Windows 7 and I have tested the same app on different versions of android 5, 5.1, 6.0. (Samsung + Sony)

It used to work before and display alert that 'Location is enabled/disabled'.

Comment: You need to be more specific than "it's not working". Describe the expected vs the actual behaviour. Give details of your test environment, e.g. device running Android 7.1.1.  If there are JS or native error messages generated, please post them: try connecting Chrome Dev Tools to the Webview to view JS errors and place breakpoints in the code to step-through debug it.

Comment: @DaveAlden done that

Answer (score 3, accepted):

> it shows the error 'cannot read property isLocationEnabled' of undefined.

This indicates the `cordova.plugins.diagnostic` object is not available.

This is most commonly caused by attempting to invoke a plugin before the `deviceready` event has fired, since Cordova dynamically loads the JS components of plugins at runtime.

Another potential cause is the plugin is not installed into the project properly - check in Chrome Dev tools if `diagnostic.js` is listed in Sources. If not present, do `cordova platform rm android && cordova platform add android` to rebuild the native Android project.

Comment: I checked the browser, diagnostic.js is not listed in the sources. Also I did remove android platform and added it again. Still same issue. The plugins folder in the app contains cordova.plugins.diagnostic and there is an entry about it inside config.xml still it isn't working.

Comment: `I checked the browser` - you mean Chrome DevTools connected to the Android device (`cordova run android`), right?  Because of course the plugin won't work in the browser enviroment (`cordova run browser`) because it requires a native mobile environment

Comment: Yes I again removed platform android and added again. Connected my phone with DevTools 'cordova run android'. The first time the plugin worked properly and an alert appeared 'location is disabled'. When I started the app second time, it is again not working.
The console shows 'cannot read property diagnostic of undefined'.

Comment: Finally solved it by calling this function inside device ready function. Thank you @DaveAlden